# Original paper of the F. &M. Riesz theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, reference-request, analytic-functions, hardy-spaces

This is not actually a question!

I need a copy of F. & M. Riesz theorem

F. and M. Riesz, Über die Randwerte einer analytischen Funktion, Quatrième Congrès des Mathématiciens Scandinaves, Stockholm, (1916), pp. 27-44.

Could someone help me to access this article?

P.S. As I mentioned in a reply, I was finally able to find the document; I'm wondering if an English translation of the paper is available.

Comment: Probably a superfluous remark: But do you really need the article or just a proof of the result (which may be found in Rudin: R & C analysis, 3rd edition, thm 17.13, p 341)

Comment: I need the original statment of theorem, as you know there are many equivalent statments of the Riesz brothers theorem. I have seen Rudin's book that you mentioned. Thanks any way @H.H.Rugh

Comment: Thanks a lot for follow up of my request, I have not seen any digital copy of the paper on the internet @kimchilover

Comment: Bingo: https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=coo.31924001079296;view=2up;seq=34;skin=mobile is it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your follow up, but content of above site you mentioned  are unavailable due to copyright. @kimchilover

Comment: I can see the whole paper.  Just click on the page and it thumbs to the next page.

Comment: @HamedPourmohammad Have you been able to see the paper yet?  The executive summary is: "Die Gesamtheit der Nullstellen der Randfunktiion einer innerhalb eines Kreises regulär analytischen und beschränkten Funktion $f(z)$ ist vom Masse Null."

Comment: @DisintegratingByParts It seems that this depends on the country where you are accessing this from. If I go to the [link from the previous comment](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=coo.31924001079296;view=2up;seq=34;skin=mobile) I get this message: "This item is not available online ( Limited - search only) due to copyright restrictions. [Learn More](https://www.hathitrust.org/help_copyright#RestrictedAccess)."

Comment: Finally I get the paper. Thank you for help @kimchilover

Answer (score 1):

The paper was reprinted in *Collected Papers* of [Marcel Riesz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marcel_Riesz#Publications) (Springer, 1988).

So you can get the paper simply by getting this book. (If your institution does not have the book in library, you can always try [interlibrary loan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interlibrary_loan).)

You can see some parts of the paper in Google Books. (This specific paper is on pages [195](https://books.google.com/books?id=FKb8wL3gUKIC&pg=PA195)-[212](https://books.google.com/books?id=FKb8wL3gUKIC&pg=PA212)).

---

As mentioned in the comments, the paper seems to be available also online as a part of HathiTrust digital library; see here for the [specific record](https://catalog.hathitrust.org/Record/101962685).

However, the access might depend on your geographic location. As they explain on [their website](https://www.hathitrust.org/help_copyright#RestrictedAccess):

> [Why is access to some items restricted?](https://www.hathitrust.org/help_copyright#RestrictedAccess)
>
> Many works in our collection are protected by copyright law, so we cannot ordinarily publicly display large portions of those protected works unless we have permission from the copyright holder. Where we have the right to show page images of works, we will make every effort to do so. We are currently displaying works that are in the public domain (such as US works published before 1923), uncopyrightable works (such as works of the US government), or works where we have permission from the copyright holder. If we cannot determine the copyright or permission status of a work, we restrict access to that work until we can establish its status.
>
> Because of differences in international copyright laws, access is also restricted for users outside the United States to works published outside the United States after and including 1877. See "[What are the different Copyright statuses of items in HathiTrust, and what do they mean?](https://www.hathitrust.org/help_copyright#RightsCodes)" below for more information about this restriction.
>
> Please use the feedback form at the top of each page to let us know if our records are incorrectly restricting access to an item. For more information, see the page on HathiTrust [Rights Management](https://www.hathitrust.org/rights_management) and the [Access and Use Policy](https://www.hathitrust.org/access_use).

Comment: Thank you so much. As you mentioned paper is seems to be available online (not for me actually), and was printed also printed in collected works of M. Riesz (and probably F. Riesz) which both where not in my university`s library!
Finally I get the paper by a request to Mittag-Lefler institute. They kindly emailed me a copy of the paper. Thanks everyone!